# How to use Handle without increase Memory in Android

Tags: java, android, android-handler, android-thread

In my application I use `ViewPager` for show some data and I want set **auto scroll** between of pages in every **5sec**.

I use below code for auto scroll between of pages in every 5sec.

```
private int page = 0;
private Handler handler;
private int delay = 5000;
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (homeRecentPostAdapter.getCount() == page) {
            page = 0;
        } else {
            page++;
        }
        homePage_recentViewPager.setCurrentItem(page, true);
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
};

    homePage_recentViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            page = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Without use this `Thread` and `Handle` **memory** usage (into **profiler** tab) has **80mb**, but after use above codes for set **auto scroll** memory usage upper to **120mb** and every 5 set upper this usage, then after **2min** receive to **250mb** !

How can I fix it? how can use auto scroll without increase memory ?

Answer (score -1):

check your `ViewPager`, maybe it is creating new instance on each page turn.
If your provide the code I might be able to point it out.